# what is wrong with this mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `) AS county FROM q_mem_tim` at line 2

```
SELECT Count( *  ) AS m, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN y = '2011' THEN 1
             ELSE 0 ) AS county
  FROM q_mem_tim
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you are not giving a lot to work with here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS m, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN y = '2011' THEN 1
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS county
  FROM q_mem_tim
```

A `CASE` statement requires the `END` keyword to indicate when it ends.